# About a presentation of a FpGroup

Tags: gap

I'm studying a group in GAP, and I have a list of relators of this finited presented group. My trouble is, this group has too many relations (actually more than 500), and GAP gives me these relations (maybe not) randomly. I want to write the presentation of this group more elegantly, is there a way GAP give me these relations in a certain order? I mean, return me first conjugations, then powers, then commutators, etc.
I wanna write the presentation using the pattern in the relations, and the command I'm using to take this relations is RelatorsOfFpGroup.

Comment: The relators are simply given in the order they were given when the group was created. So if you give then in nice order, GAP returns them in nice order. Or are you talking about *operations* that calculate a presentation of a group given in another representation?